# Explain PHP/MySQL in Simple Terms

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below and was hoping someone could clarify what the highlighted/commented/obvious lines was doing please

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `tblName` WHERE `id`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']) . "' LIMIT 0, 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach($row as $name => $value) {  // THIS ONE I NEED HELP WITH
    ...
}
```

Does it basically say "for each column..." - this is where I get stuck

Comment: Hardly simple terms! Let's assume I need to explain it to my mother or child.... or at least a colleague who understands databases but not PHP

Comment: @JeremyHarris that hardly is going to help OP. "*This question concerns how it works under the bonnet*" OP is **not** looking for that

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: You're right, it basically says "in the row of data returned, take each column as $name and it's value as $value".

Comment: @tadman - indeed, this is just a very very simplified version

Comment: @PeeHaa I was hoping that OP was confused about something more in-depth than can be easily Googled. For example: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/php-in-a/0596100671/ch04s11.html

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It always helps.

Comment: @pee2pee Parameterized queries are often more simplified than this alternative since the query itself isn't broken up into bits and cluttered up with all sorts of escaping junk. If you can keep your code simple you can keep it understandable.

Comment: @JeremyHarris you must be new here :P

Comment: I fail to see the value of this question as this is simple code that uses functions that are clearly explained in the official PHP documenation.

Comment: @JeremyHarris how does that relate to a DB query though. In a normal for loop, yes, but in a MySQL situation, I wanted it to be clear

Comment: T'is the season to be jolly.... unless you're on SO :-)

Comment: @pee2pee I have a massive answer written, but the question was closed (in fairness I started that close vote). Maybe it will help: http://pastebin.com/f5hXdgD4

Comment: Luckily,  the beauty of prepared statements is such that you never need concern yourself with such archaic code.

Comment: I know, I know...

Comment: @juergend wth did you dupe close it against the thing we all agreed on was not a dupe? It should be closed but that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `foreach` loop.  So it can be translated to...

*for every object in the `$row` variable, assign that object to the new variable `$name`, with its corresponding value as `$value`*

That will loop N times, where N is the number of rows returned.  Each time the loop is iterated, the `$name` and `$value` variables are re-initialized to the new row's contents.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure it included the column names rather than just records

Comment: Yes. That's what adding the `=>` does.

Comment: Will accept this as answer as soon as I can

Comment: That's not at all "what the `=>` does", `$name` will contain the row's *numeric* index in the result set, and `$value` will contain the row itself. Whether or not the row includes the column names depends entirely on which `fetch` function is called. In this case calling `fetch_assoc` is what gets the column names as keys in the `$row` array.